# Transforming queries: right joins to left joins

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

Suppose I have following tables: T1,T2 and T3.
How could I rephrase the following query using only left joins.

```
 Select *
From T1
Right join T2 On T1.FK2=T2.PK
Right join T3 On T1.FK3=T3.PK
```

Following attempt is not correct:

```
Select *
From T2
Left join T1 On T1.FK2=T2.PK
Left join T3 On T1.FK3=T3.PK
```

T3 is On the wrong Side of the join. Is the following possible:

```
Select *
From T2
Left join T3 On T1.FK3=T3.PK
Left join T1 On T1.FK2=T2.PK
```

I can't Find a way to put both tables 2 and 3 On the left Side of 1 and use the correspondent fields to join all tables? The last query uses fields of table 1 before this table is mentioned in the query.

Or something like this?

```
Select *
From T2
Left join (
   T3 left join T1
       On T1.FK3=T3.PK)
   On T1.FK2=T2.PK
```

Comment: unclear what you asking. can you show sample data and your wished result?

Comment: why would you need that?

Comment: I'm currently programming a query visualizer. And i'm stick on this hypothetical question

Comment: well you cannot do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently brackets can help to order your joins. I wonder if this is really documented, i've found Nothing at first glance in the mysql docs.
Following query is correct and does not have any subqueries:

```
Select T1.Id Ida, t2.id idb, T3.id idc FROM T3
LEFT JOIN 
   (T2
      LEFT JOIN T1 ON (T1.ID = T2.ID))
ON (T1.ID= T3.ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a subquery to first join t1 with t2 and then join the result with t3:

```
SELECT T.ID1 ID1, T.ID2 ID2, T3.ID ID3 FROM T3
 LEFT JOIN 
 (SELECT T1.ID ID1, T2.ID ID2 FROM T2
  LEFT JOIN T1 ON (T1.ID = T2.ID)) T
 ON (T.ID1 = T3.ID);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48943/17)

Comment: Doesn't this impact the performance? And is there really a need to use subqueries?

Comment: Yes, you need to use subqueries, if you want identical results. What comes to performance: profile both queries.

Comment: Execution plans on oracle seem to be identical

Comment: I've fiddled a bit with your query: [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48943/28) this works perfect thanks

Comment: I must say that I haven't seen this notation used before. It seems to be logically equivalent, but is indeed much cleaner

Answer (score 0):

The first way is just to reverse the order that the tables are mentioned:

```
Select *
from t3 left outer join
     t2
     on T1.FK3 = T3.PK left outer join
     t1
     on T1.FK2 = T2.PK
```

But this won't work, because the first condition is on `t1` and not `t2`.  And `t2` hasn't yet been defined.

When working with chains of tables in left or right outer joins, only the first (or last) tables are important, because they "drive" the query.  "Drive" in the sense that they provide all the values even when there are no matches.  So, the following should do what you want:

```
Select *
from t3 left outer join
     t1
     on T1.FK3 = T3.PK left outer join
     t2
     on T1.FK2 = T2.PK;
```

Comment: This one is not correct because it reeds as t1 left Join t2, which is incorrect!

Comment: @Bee157 . . . No.  It it reads at t3 left join t1 left join t2.  It is all important that the chain starts with t3.

Comment: I agree but The original right joined query does not return any row from t1 if it has no link with t3 or t2, yours does. So this response is not correct.

Comment: @Bee157 . . . That would be an incorrect result with a `right outer join`.  A chain of right outer joins should be returning all values from the last table mentioned.  Can you set up a SQL Fiddle with your table structures and sample data?

Comment: Here is an [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48943/28). The structure is purely hypothetical, but shows The differences between the queries.